# How to replace this for loop with matrix operations in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I know that writing a for loop in Matlab is typically not efficient.
Now I am trying to replace a nested for loop with a better option.
Here is the nested loop,

```
for i = 1: size(A,1)
   for j = 1: size(B,1)
      S(i,j, :) = c*(A(i,:)*a - B(j,:)*b);
   end
end
```

What operation should I use? (I was thinking about Cartesian product implementation)

Comment: What dimension are the inputs?

Comment: A is 1000*500, B is 300*40, a  is  500* 5, and  b is 40*5, c is 1*1.

Comment: you have a problem with dimensions following the code in the question...

Comment: The function including this piece of code is called 10^6 times, so any speed up in this, will end up to speed ups in the whole procedure.

Comment: The dimensions I mentioned can be much larger depending on inputs as well, so I am more interested in knowing how to eliminate the for loop, than how to make the for loop work for my size.

Comment: Regardless of what approach you take recognizing that A*a and B*b are being recomputed many times above and from your dimensions it is both a data reduction and a savings in computation to precompute them.   Looks like all the solutions take advantage of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following

```
AA = permute(A * a, [1, 3, 2]);
BB = permute(B * b, [3, 1, 2]);
CC = c * bsxfun(@minus, AA, BB);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know a good reference to learn these elements for more stylistic Matlab coding, like bsxfun. I am not aware of them, and finding them out in a very hard way, one by one.

Comment: I don't use indirect functions very often,  as I expect a substantial performance penalty for doing so. I suppose that could be a hold over from my experiences in older versions of matlab though.

Comment: Sometimes tic-toc surprises me.   This solution .00604s,  my solution .01329s,  @Luis Mendo solution .704s.

Answer (score 1):

```
    A=(1:20)'*ones(1,10);
    size(A)   % 20,10
    a=ones(10,1)*(1:5);
    size(a)    %10,5
    B=ones(3,1)*(1:20);
    size(B)    %3,20
    b=ones(20,1)*(1:5);
    size(b)    %20,5
    c=1;
    Aa=A*a;
    size(Aa)   %20,5
    Bb=B*b;
    size(Bb)    %3,5
    na=size(Aa,1);
    nb=size(Bb,1);
    Ia=(1:na)'* ones(1,nb);
    %Ia=1;2;3..nb;1;2;3..nb na times
    Ia=reshape(Ia,na*nb,1);
    %Ib=1;1;natimes;2;2;2 natimes...nb;nb;nb...natimes
    Ib=ones(na,1)*(1:nb);
    Ib=reshape(Ib,na*nb,1);
    S=(Aa(Ia,:)-Bb(Ib,:))*c;
    S=reshape(S,[na nb size(Aa,2)]);
```

Comment: Thanks I had not thought about it this way. The specific code, does not seem to work though.

Comment: @user25004  Test environment was octave rather than matlab, but I'm usually pretty good at staying consistent between the two.  Had hand transcribed from the test script before, but here it is cut and paste from the original.

Answer (score 1):

```
nA = size(A,1);
nB = size(B,1);
Ar = repmat(A, nB, 1); %// repeat A along rows
Br = B(ceil(1/nA:1/nA:nB), :); %// stretch B along rows
S = c*(Ar*a-Br*b); %// do the computations
S = reshape(permute(S, [1 3 2]), nA, nB, []); %// put into shape
```

Comment: @user25004 Hmm... I learned Matlab just from an old manual, and then using it a lot. StackOverflow has also helped. And of course there's the Matlab online documentation